# How can I delete the last page of multiple PDFs at once?

Tags: pdf

I have a large number of PDFs, each PDF has a varying amount of pages. I need to delete always the last page of each PDF.

I was wondering if you guys know of any free software that can do this in a batch processing mode (all at once)?

For now, I only found PDF splitters, but those create individual pdfs from different pages. Of course, I could then join them back together and avoid the last page, but this would be extremely time consuming and prone to failure, because I have 100+ PDFs, with at least 10 pages each.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Which OS? Adobe acrobat ?